# Algolia search within scope

Tags: algolia

I am trying to implement Algolia for a directory. I've created a huge index for listings with data like:

```
{
  "id": 120,
  "listing_type": "restaurant",
  "location": "In example street, so so area",
  "brand":{
    "name": "Mc Donald's",
    "image":"1130824.jpg",
    "description": "Find fastest burgers and fries around. "
  },
  "neighbourhood":{
    "name": "Downtown",
    "city":{
      "name": "Philadelphia",
      "state": "PA"
    }
  },
  "_tags":["burgers","fries","fast food","quick service"],
  "has_deals": true,
  "images":["file1.jpg","file2.jpg"],
...
}
```

I want to create separate pages for each city, and would like to restrict searches for that specific city. How can I achieve this?

I can find a parameter that can be added here:

```
var search = instantsearch({
    // Replace with your own values
    appId: 'xxxxxx',
    apiKey: 'xxxx', // search only API key, no ADMIN key
    indexName: 'listings',
    urlSync: true,
    searchParameters: {
        hitsPerPage: 10
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to restrict a search, both based on the `filters`. For that you first need to add some single attribute you can filter on for the city to `attributesForFaceting` (in the settings, for example with the dashboard). In this case we can use `neighbourhood.city`.

Then in InstantSearch on your page you can add to `searchParameters` the value: `filters: 'neighbourhood.city:Philadelphia'`.

You can also use "secured API keys" to refine on this value *before* actually launching the page. This will prevent someone from taking that API key and searching themselves. Read more about that in the [docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/security/api-keys/secured-api-keys/how-to-restrict-the-search-to-a-subset-of-records-belonging-to-a-specific-user/#before-starting)